# Is the definition of conditional probability misleading

Tags: probability, statistics, definition

I am learning probability and statistics from the book *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis, 3rd Edition* by Rice. However just couple pages reading I think his definition on conditional probability is incomplete and misleading.
[image: his definition on probability measure]

Notice that function P only takes subset of Ω, nothing else.

Now here is his definition on conditional probability:

[image: definition on conditional probability]

The problem is that the P in left is not the same P as in right. Firstly lets ask what is A|B. If A|B is a subset of Ω, then what is the exact components of that? Its awkward to assign anythings into it because really you can't if you use the old P. P on Ω is fundamentally updated by knowing that B is true. So in old P P(B)=something, in new P P(B)=1, and all elements associated with B got updated value. In new P we can say that A|B = A ∩ B or A|B = A.

But all those are not clearly stated in his definition (in his following explanation he said the sample space becomes B rather than Ω, which is even more misleading because Ω doesn't need to change).

Is my understanding correct? Thanks for any help.

A following question can be found in here:
[Fallacy on using interpretation instead of definition in computing conditional probability? (using multiplication law circularly?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411277/fallacy-on-using-interpretation-instead-of-definition-in-computing-conditional-p)

(also I think its best not to define conditional probability this way. This should be a result instead of a definition.)

Comment: $A\mid B$ is not a thing. $P(A\mid B)$ is (a conditional probability). By itself $A\mid B$ has no meaning.

Comment: There are indeed some things not clearly stated here. This already starts with the definition of probability measure which really needs the notion of $\sigma$-algebra (at least you need the countable union of measurable subsets to be measurable, so that part 3 makes sense). On the other hand, you might have the misconception that $A|B$ denotes some set which is then plugged into the measure $P$ and this is not the case. Given $P$ and $B$ with $P(B) \neq 0$ we get a *new* probability measure which we call $P(\cdot | B)$ and which maps a subset $A$ to $P(A \cap B)/P(B)$.

Comment: The $P$s doesn't need be different and $A\mid B$ doesn't need to be "nothing". We can define $A\mid B$ to be distinct from any events (call it a conditional event). That way we can define $P$ to map between the set of events or coditional event to probability (defininig the probability of a conditional event according to the formula above).

Comment: $P(A\mid B)$ is just a peculiar notation. The function $P(\cdot \mid B)$ is a new probability measure on $\Omega$. You might prefer to denote this new probability measure as $P_{\mid B}$ or something like that. So then $P_{\mid B}(A) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$ .

Comment: @skyking This would be a source of confusion (as exhibit, see quite a few questions about this subject on this very site), with no advantage I can see. Sorry but, as others have said, **A|B does not exist**.

Comment: You are thinking of $P$ as a function of one argument which is "$A \mid B$".  But that is not the correct interpretation.  You should think of $P(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ as a function of two arguments which are $A$ and $B$, which just happens to look similar to the one-argument function $P$.

Comment: @Did What I meant was that while we (normally) define $P(A\mid B)$ as an immediate construct out of $P$, $A$ and $B$ as mentioned, there's nothing hindering defining the construct as an composite construct by first defining $A\mid B$ and out of that defining $P(A\mid B)$ - for example as I mentioned. Of course that wouldn't be considered standard, but you're welcome to point out any actual incompatibilities in such constructs if you're thinking that couldn't be done (I myself will **not** point out any advantages in that construct as my point was only that it was a possibility).

Comment: @skyking Usually, one suggests deviations from the canon when they have an advantage, here you suggest one with no advantage at all (you say), only the (huge) disadvantage of comforting beginners in their misconceptions? Sorry but I am not following. And what kind of object would be A|B anyway? If this is a notation for the (ordered) couple (A,B), let us stick to (A,B), shall we?

Comment: @Did I mention the possibility to define $A\mid B$ to be something on it's own. There's various possibilities and it need not necessarily be an ordered pair. Besides that there exists another notation available need not be an argument for disallowing another notation for formally the same thing.

Comment: @skyking Yeah, you keep repeating that but we still do not know precisely what it is you suggest to define (let alone why such a definition should be the least interesting, in fact you more or less admit it would not). Oddly, the only suggestion of a coherent definition of A|B, so far, is in **my** comment (but it is completely uninteresting, of course). Sorry but at present you seem to be essentially making noise to "save" a suggestion that cannot be saved. Better to drop it and to go back doing actual maths, no?

Comment: @Did Perhaps it's differences in language, but I don't think I'm suggesting (ie advocating) anything. I only point out a possibility. As that I don't think I have anything that needs saving - the possibility is there, at least nobody have pointed out why it would not be able to work (confusing those who misunderstand a definition is IMHO **not** an indication that something can't work).

Comment: @skyking To complain that "nobody ha(s) pointed out why it would not be able to work" when we do not even know what "it" is (what is your suggestion exactly, except to use the notation A|B, for purposes you never mention?), and which "work" it could accomplish, requires a dose of chutzpah. When the suggestion is so vague and so out of the canon, the onus is on the person who is making it, right? Except that here, we do not even know what it is exactly that is suggested... As already said: better to drop it altogether.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely have a point if you observe an old and a new $P$.

Actually if $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ is a probability space then  every $B\in\mathcal A$ with $P(B)>0$ somehow induces a *new* probability space $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P_B\rangle$ where $P_B$ is defined by:$$P_B(A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Subscript $B$ emphasizes that we are dealing with a probability that depends on $B$.

If you are dealing with probabilities conditional with respect to $B$ then in fact tacitly you have stepped over to that space.

A nicer and generally accepted notation for $P_B(A)$ is $P(A\mid B)$.

I think it is the best here if you interpret $P(A\mid B)$ as nothing else but an abbreviation of $\frac{P(A\cap B}{P(B)}$.

Keeping in mind of course that you dealing with conditional probabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I think the formal definition written in wikipedia is much clear and better. The equation should be a derived result instead of a definition in the beginning. Although the new problem will be what precisely is the elementary events. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Formal_derivation

Comment: I agree that $P_B(A)$ is preferable to $P(A|B),$ but the latter is so widely used that a campaign to make the change would very likely fail. In applications, it is important to keep in mind is the _different populations_ to which $P(A|B),\,P(B|A),$ and $P(A \cap B)$ apply. Especially so in the statement and proof of Bayes' Theorem, where all three may be relevant. // A related issue in applications is to distinguish whether $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ is an _assumption_ for modeling independence in a situation or a _condition_ to be tested for a model already specified.